Automatic flush of stream when reading input
I read in Advanced Programming in Unix Environment this:

Line buffering comes with two caveats. First, the size of the buffer
that the standard I/O library uses to collect each line is fixed, so
I/O might take place if we fill this buffer before writing a newline.
Second, whenever input is requested through the standard I/O library
from either (a) an unbuffered stream or (b) a line-buffered stream
(that requires data to be requested from the kernel), all
line-buffered output streams are flushed. The reason for the qualifier
on (b) is that the requested data may already be in the buffer, which
doesn’t require data to be read from the kernel. Obviously, any input
from an unbuffered stream, item (a), requires data to be obtained from
the kernel.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html states:

Flushing output on a buffered stream means transmitting all
accumulated characters to the file. There are many circumstances when
buffered output on a stream is flushed automatically:
When you try to do output and the output buffer is full.
When the stream is closed. See Closing Streams.
When the program terminates by calling exit. See Normal Termination.
When a newline is written, if the stream is line buffered.
Whenever an input operation on any stream actually reads data from its
file.

So I've written a program to test this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    FILE *fp = fopen("hugefile", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    setvbuf(fp, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    sleep(2);
    char buf[10];

    while (fread(buf, sizeof(char), 10, fp) == 10) {
    }

    if (ferror(fp)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Read error\n");
        return -1;
    }; // I expect "Hello" to appear on a screen but it doesn't
    fclose(fp);
    sleep(50);
}

But fread() doesn't trigger flashing of the output. Am I missing something?
I don't know what might be relevant here but I use:
gcc version 14.2.1 20240910
glibc 2.40+r16+gaa533d58ff-2

You would like to see contents of hugefile?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk, it's a movie file:
ls -lhn hugefile:
-rwxr-x--- 1 1002 1000 561M Nov  9 12:22 hugefile

You might want to check the result from setvbuf(). It may be rejected, as it is probably physically impossible to read a block-buffered device without a (hidden) block-sized buffer. Maybe running under strace would be helpful.

I think that flushing the buffer doesn't imply it will be printed to
the screen or whatever stdout is redirected to.
Flushing stdout by reading from stdin:
You can achieve the behavior the following buf.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello");
  sleep(2);
  fprintf(stderr, "No output from stdout after 2 seconds\n");

  char buf[10];
  while (fread(buf, sizeof(char), 10, stdin) == 10) {
  }

  sleep(5);
}

Run it:
$ ./buf
No output from stdout after 2 seconds
Hello

"Hello" string is printed to stdout and does not end with a newline)
(\n) so it's not flushed after 2 seconds but it's flushed when
fread() is run. If it was removed it would be flushed only after
last sleep.
Whenever an input operation on any stream actually reads data from its
file.
Flushing to file by reading from file:
To reproduce Whenever an input operation on any stream actually reads
data from its file. which I think was your main goal:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp = fopen("FILE", "a+");
  fprintf(fp, "add more characters to FILE\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "wrote more characters to FILE\n");
  sleep(5);

  fprintf(stderr, "reading will now start\n");
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  char buf[10];
  while (fread(buf, sizeof(char), 10, fp) == 10) {

  }

  fprintf(stderr, "Sleep for 5 seconds before sleep()\n");
  sleep(5);
  fprintf(stderr, "Exit\n");
}

Run it like that, I will a small FILE that only contain a current date
and will run a binary in the background so that I would be able to see
all messages it prints and be able to examine contents of FILE at the
same time:
$ date > FILE
$ ./buf &
[1] 14522
wrote more characters to FILE
$ cat FILE
Sat Nov  9 13:02:28 CET 2024
$ reading will now start
Sleep for 5 seconds before sleep()

$ cat FILE
Sat Nov  9 13:02:28 CET 2024
add more characters to FILE
Exit

As you see add more characters to FILE line has been added to FILE
only after fread() was run.

Thanks for response.


You open stream in append mode and read from it. I suppose this triggers undefined behavior because you can't read from such streams. Moreover in file opened read-write you can't jump between reading/writing without some fflush, fseek or whatever in-between them.


In my, possibly wrong, interpretation APUE and GCC docs talk about different streams and how reading from one of them, triggers the flush on the other. The 1st example with stdin/stdout show that, it would be more educational to see it on a different pair of streams as this concrete case feels natural.




thx, I fixed my post 2. I can reproduce your original problem, I also don't get "Hello". The conclusion is that an explanation in Advanced Programming in Unix Environment doesn't apply to glibc. Some even say this practice is harmful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536212/what-are-the-rules-of-automatic-stdout-buffer-flushing-in-c#comment115504305_39536336. I don't know if glibc implementation is explained in detail, reading the source code is a huge pain.

